# Vue JS router component - Cannot re-use JS file that uses webpack imports after navigating between routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-router

Alright, so this issue I'm having is a bit complicated but I'll try to be as clear as possible with what's happening here.
First of all, I am using the latest Vue and Vue-Router in my application with webpack.

This is a single-file component named

> CP.vue

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        created() {
            Load();
            const JS = () => import('cp.js');
            JS();
            console.log("created");

        },
        mounted() {
            Show();
        },
        destroyed() {
            console.log("destroyed");
        },
        methods: { }

    }
</script>
```

And this is how cp.js begins

> cp.js

```
console.log("cp created");

// Bootstrap Datepicker
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css';
// Switchery
import '../../../node_modules/mohithg-switchery/switchery.css';
// TreeView CSS 
import '../../../node_modules/patternfly-bootstrap-treeview/dist/bootstrap-treeview.css';
// Datatables CSS 
import '../../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css';
// Datatables - Button CSS 
import '../../../node_modules/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.scss';
/////////////////////////// Toastr - for warnings
import '../../../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css';
////////////////////////// ScrollBar 
import '../../../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/src/css/main.scss';
// CSS
import '../../scss/pages/cp.scss';

.....
.... more JS code which never works the second time
.....

/*----------  DatePicker  ----------*/

const datePicker = $('#date-range').datepicker({
    toggleActive: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: 'today',
    maxDate: 'today',
    startDate: '01/01/2014'
});
/*----------  ScrollBar  ----------*/

$('#tree-container').perfectScrollbar();
// there's more, but it's a long file so I cut it short
```

^ The modules here are loaded with lazy-load.
When I first navigate to the path of CP.vue, the template shows and the JS file loads fine. You can see "cp created" in the console.
However, when I move to a path of another component in the vue router and then return to /cp, all the functionalities from cp.js no longer work (date picker, etc), while the style it imported on the first time is still intact, and console.log("cp created") doesn't even run, which means it only loads cp.js once, and when you re-navigate to /cp the functions of the script are gone. So you have to refresh the page for it to work again which is exactly what I don't want to do hence the reason I'm using VueRouter.
I tried searching for people who had the issue all over the internet, tried plugins like "vue-plugin-load-script" to try and unload the script and load it again whenever the component is created and destroyed, but nothing works. Only the approach with using this code

```
const JS = () => import('cp.js');
JS();
```

To even load the js file works because plugins like "vue-plugin-load-script" don't recognize esx syntax.

Does anyone know a way I can reuse cp.js eveytime the component is created again when I navigate between components in vue router? Or maybe a different approach that will work for loading that JS file...
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a 'keep-alive' tag around your 'router-view' or somewhere else that may block the component to be created again ?

Comment: @qwsd The thing is that the component IS created again. You can see the console.log("created") for that vue component, it just doesn't import the JS file the second time.

Comment: Try to move `const JS = () => import('cp.js');` from created to import section. The script won't fetch until you use your component somewhere, same effect as you put it into `create`

Comment: @deathangel908 I did move it to the import section in main.js where I load everything (which is not the right way to do this but okay) and it still does the same thing.

Comment: What do you want from the script you import? To run it twice? The scripts in browser (in node as well) are evaluated only once, that's just how it works. You should move your code to the function inside your cp.js and import this function where you need it.  In your case you could call it from create. Leave imports outside of this function, they are evaluated during compile time to assemble your cp.js

Comment: @deathangel908 You're missing the problem. When loading that JS file, it's looking for certain elements at runtime. It can't run outside of the component because the component is created only when you view it in your router view, and destroyed when you navigate to another component. So I load the JS file when the component is created, and when I move to another and come back, it doesn't load it again but it's also no longer functional, as if it's no longer there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In your case style-loader generates code that applies css file when script is evaluated, there's no such functionality by default as unloading css files. Check this [repo](https://github.com/akoidan/test), everything works. When you navigate to num page background becomes red and never goes back to its first state

Comment: @deathangel908 The thing is, as I said in the post, the css files stay intact and loaded. It's the JS functions that are no longer defined, and so I can't use them.

Comment: Whether you're defining them in global scope like `window.a = 'b'`, or exporting them from cp.js as `export` they should be defined, I'm not sure what you mean by phrase `they are no longer defined`. Defined where? I don't know the 3rd way of accessing module functions

Comment: @deathangel908 There are many event listeners and functions in that cp.js. For example, when you click on a certain input on this template in the vue component, the date picker is supposed to pop up. It works on the first time you navigate to the cp component. But once you navigate to another component (ex. /main) and go back to /cp, it no longer works. As if the JS code is no longer loaded. And it doesn't load it again too. (with JS = () => import('cp.js'); JS(); inside of the created() function of the vue component). That is my issue.

Comment: Please attach that js code to your question and exceptions (if you get any)

Comment: @deathangel908 Just edited and attached a small bit, since the js file is really long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said you should redesign your code. The script is evaluated only once, you could do nothing about it, and it's the right way it should work.

**cp.js**:

```
export function initComponents()  {
  const datePicker = $('#date-range').datepicker({
    toggleActive: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: 'today',
    maxDate: 'today',
    startDate: '01/01/2014'
  });
  /*----------  ScrollBar  ----------*/

  $('#tree-container').perfectScrollbar();
}
```

and from your component:

```
import( /* webpackChunkName: "cp.js" */ 'cp.js').then(exports => {
  exports.initComponents();
});
```

**EDIT**:
Also it's bad practice defining component ids in your custom file. I would recommend to use vue-datepickers. [There're a lot of them](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue) Well, if you still wanna use custom datepicker, you could pass `htmlNode` as parameter to your initComponent function. But I guess the best choice would be creating component named datePicker and put all `js` code into `create` method there. Also you could pack your css files into `scoped` css section instead of having global css.

Comment: I moved all of the JS code that's after the imports to the initComponents export function, and imported cp.js just the way you did in the created function of my cp component. It works!!! Great answer. It's strange that this isn't written anywhere, given that so many people use Vue and VueRouter with webpack and esx and NEED components to function this way. Thank you